# Need to find lidl font

Tags: font-identification

does anyone know what is that font used in this lidl logo? I need just a part of word Lidl in it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The font is called [Oberon](http://www.findmyfont.com/index.php/fonts/font-preview?fset=Linotype%20%2F%20%28Commercial%29&ffam=Oberon%20LET%20-%20Plain&fid=4121006ffd1b57630c40bd5e6fb10789&fsize=60&text=Lidl&fit=1) available through Linotype. Note FindMyFont is a site I work for.
[image: Oberon font preview].